# Volley passing URL

Tags: java, android, jsoup, android-volley

```
final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.show();

StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        "http://example.com/", new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);

        Elements elementss = document.select("div.category > li");

        for (Element element : elements) {


            Elements naslov = el.select("div.text > li.headline);



        }

        pDialog.hide();

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Greška", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pDialog.hide();
    }
});

AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
```

How could I pass URL parameter, instead of creating new StringRequest everytime i want to parse data, because different URLs have the same HTML structure, could I pass URL parameter when adding StringRequest to RequestQueue, something like:

```
AppCore.getInstance("http://example.com/").addToRequestQueue(strReq);
```

And use the same StringRequest several times, but with different URLs?

Also, here's my AppCore.java:

```
package app.android.volley;

import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;


public class AppCore extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppCore.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppCore mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppCore getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

**Basically what I'm trying to do is using one StringRequest multiple times, but with different URLs.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way (of course, you can replace `JSONArray` request by `JSONObject` request or `String` request):

```
VolleyResponseListener listener = new VolleyResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(String message) {
                // do something...
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object response) {
                // do something...
            }
        };

makeJsonArrayRequest(context, Request.Method.POST, url, requestBody, listener);
```

Body of `makeJsonArrayRequest` can be as the following:

```
    public void makeJsonArrayRequest(Context context, int method, String url, String requestBody, final VolleyResponseListener listener) {
        JSONObject jsonRequest = null;        
        try {
            ...
            if (requestBody != null) {
                jsonRequest = new JSONObject(requestBody);
            }
            ...
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(method, url, jsonRequest, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                listener.onResponse(jsonArray);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                listener.onError(error.toString());
            }
        });

        // Access the RequestQueue through singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

`VolleyResponseListener` interface as the following:

```
public interface VolleyResponseListener {
    void onError(String message);

    void onResponse(Object response);
}
```